# How might I improve my question?

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question, and I feel that boardgames is the correct place to be asking it (as opposed to ux etc) that is about board game design. At the risk of the meta-effect the question is here https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20410/which-design-is-clearest-to-indicate-failure-consequence.

I've received 2 downvotes, I'm assuming because my question could be taken as a bit subjective. I'd really like to improve it if the community feel that it is too subjective, so I'm opening this up, to ask what might I be able to do to improve it?

I'd like to keep the question in some form, as I've already had 2 comments that provide really great feedback even if they have not yet proposed an answer, so I'd appreciate any suggestions on what I may be able to do to make it a better fit.

Comment: In my opinion, this question *would* fit better at UX. They have a lot of questions in the general category "what design best communicates idea X to the user?" and in some sense that is their primary area of expertise. On this site, our expertise (or at least mine) tends more towards playing games and understanding the rules and strategies of those games.

Comment: @murgatroid99: Want to add this as an answer, and I'll move the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this question **would** fit better at UX. Your question has the form "What design best communicates idea X to the user?" which is a very common question type on UX and is in some sense their primary area of expertise. On this site, our expertise (or at least mine) tends more towards playing games and understanding the rules and strategies of those games.